# How can I control and obtain real-time return value for python script, using tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am doing a GUI for my python script, right now I'm using the Tkinter.

I write the main function a continuous `While` loop, so that it can keep tracking the data changes.
For the GUI, I created a start and end button to start running or stop the script. My problem is that, I linked the main function to the GUI module. But when I clicked the start button the GUI module just went no-responding and the main function kept running. My code looks like this,

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.startButton = Button(self, text='Start', command=main)
        self.startButton.pack()
        self.quit = Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


def main():
    While True:
       # keep running to monitor the data changing
       print(changed value) 



app = Application()
app.master.title('Auto Detection')
app.mainloop()
```

How can I control the running of the main function via GUI module, do I need to change the main function?
And can I obtain the real-time return value of the main function on the GUI?
Thanks so much.

Comment: You cannot use loops directly when using tkinter. At the very start of the program, add ```import threading as th```. Then in ```createWidgets()``` function, in the ```Start``` button, change the command to ```th.Thread(target=main).start()```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how can I exit this thread via the quit button, since it is not named?

Comment: If you want to continuously output the results to your GUI, check out the `after` method from tkinter. Maybe, it is a better fit to your needs than the `while` loop

Comment: Threads cannot be ended manually and they end when you close the window. In the quit button, instead of the command ```self.master.destroy```, use ```self.master.quit```